# How to run a SQL select statement in VB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been looking around but can't seem to find out how to do this.

I'm trying to execute a SELECT sql statement in VB that takes in a parameter from a form. For example the user selects a From and a To date and the SQL should take what they selected.

I know that you cannot use the DoCmd.Execute method for SELECT SQL so I would need to open the record set - but how? This is what I have tried so far

```
Dim recordSet As DAO.recordSet
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblWebMeetingData"
Set recordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

'More code in here

recordSet.Close

Set recordSet = Nothing
```

Because this executes without an error I assume it's actually getting the results - so is there a way to see what it is actually returning?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: It's a good advice to rename the recordset to rs, for example, because "recordset" is a reserved name. This is misunderstandable.

This recordset contains the records you queried by your SQL statement. You may access those data by `rs.fields("fieldname").value`. Move to the next recordset with `rs.movenext`.

To incorporate the form's control value I use the way to build the full SQL statement prior to opening the recordset. Say the form is named "myform" and the control "mycontrol", you may write some kind of

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblWebMeetingData WHERE myfield = " & forms!myform.mycontrol.value
```

Please be sure the form only contains valid values, because any wrong formatted value will directly lead to an SQL execution error.

I hope it was this, what you wanted.

Comment: So how would i go about looking at the different records?

Comment: See answer from Wawrzyniec Sz. Of course the way to use the data depends on what you want to do with them. If you could be more specific at that point, we may help you better :-)

Comment: Ok so the table im looking at getting data from has 19 fields, I want a sql statement in vb that will get all the data from this table based on what the user selects in a drop down box. The results of which should be written to an excel file - I can write the excel code fine but ran into problems when i tried to pass SQL to it.

Comment: What kind of information does the user select? To wich table column is this information related? Knowing this you may add some kind of `... WHERE fieldname = 'information' ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have come sample code about iterating trought RecordSet and using values from it( I hope it helps a bit):

```
Dim i As Integer
Do While Not rs.EOF
        Sheets("D_" & day).Cells(i, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
        Sheets("D_" & day).Cells(i, 2) = rs.Fields(1).Value
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
Loop

rs.Close
```